# Thesis Data Collection Mistake

Tags: thesis, data, statistics, psychology

I am currently undergoing my psychology thesis (4th year) in Australia, and have just finished data collection. I have just realised that between myself and my group, 2/3 of the questionnaires used have 1 question missing. Eg. can now only be scored out of 19, instead of 20 as data was not collected for that particular question. Does anyone know how to proceed with this or where to address this in the best way without losing marks? I cannot redo data collection, and I know this is a big mistake!

Any advice would be really appreciated as I'm feeling extremely overwhelmed and don't know where to begin.

Comment: Your supervisor(s) will be in the best position to advise on this.

Comment: @Theoretician: sounds like an answer, want to post as such?

Comment: How many total people? With enough imputation is probably feasible.

Comment: There is about 200 participants, however it is an entire item missing on two out of three of the questionnaires, so I'm not sure imputation is appropriate as it is missing that question entirely?

Answer (score 1):

So consider removing that same question from the 1/3 where it did appear. Then process the results from that complete batch for the 19 questions.

You could then consider processing the results for all 20 questions for that 1/3 and see if there is an appreciable difference. That may then give another route of investigation or further work.

However, you should discuss this with your supervisor.

Comment: Sorry I have worded it wrong, I mean in two out of my three questionnaires used, they each have an item missing - so none of the participants answered this question at all. It is for a mediation analysis, so I am unsure how to proceed.